# Why is this ruby script echoing the path to the executable?

Tags: ruby

Here's a Ruby file at `/path/to/test/test.rb`:

```
# /path/to/test/test.rb
puts 'foobar'
```

Here's what happens when I run it:

```
$ cd /path/to/test/
$ ruby test.rb
foobar
```

So far, so good. But:

```
$ cd ..
$ ruby test/test.rb
/path/to/test/         # <=== wtf?
foobar
```

Why does Ruby print the path to the script when I run it outside the current folder? The problem occurs only with Ruby scripts, and occurs whether or not I run it with `$ ruby test.rb` or make it executable with a shebang.

This is definitely nonstandard behavior caused by something in my Ruby environment, but I can't imagine what it is. I have Rails and a number of other gems installed. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the behavior you described.

Comment: Can you try to track down where the `puts` is actually coming from? Try doing something like this: `alias old_puts puts; def puts(s);  file = File.basename(caller.first); old_puts("puts() from #{file}: #{s}"); end`

Comment: Can not reproduce.

Comment: Are you by chance using rbenv?

Comment: @mwp - Yes, I'm using rbenv! Why is it doing that?

Comment: I've had this problem before but I can't remember what I did to solve it. It might help if you could tell us 1. which rbenv plugins you have installed and 2. how you are initializing rbenv in your .bashrc/.bash_profile/.profile. You might also try installing the rbenv-update plugin and updating everything (assuming you've installed your rbenv plugins manually) to see if it solves the problem. https://github.com/rkh/rbenv-update

Comment: Interesting. The only thing I do with rbenv is initialize it in `.profile` like this: `command -v rbenv > /dev/null && eval "$(rbenv init -)"`. As far as I know I have no plugins; in fact I don't have a `$RBENV_ROOT` directory defined, so I'm not sure where'd they be if I did. (I only see `$RBENV_SHELL`.)

Comment: How is rbenv installed? What OS?

Comment: @TomLord - no help, unfortunately. Printing `caller` just shows a single line, for `/path/to/test/test.rb`.

Comment: @mwp - This is on OSX. Confirmed present on two Macbooks that share my configuration (including rbenv), and absent on a third Macbook that doesn't.

Comment: @Sasgorilla What do you mean? What is the entire stacktrace for `caller`? If you got this alias to work, then it should surely show you where the call originated from; my guess is somewhere in your `rbenv` settings.

Comment: Is CDPATH set in your environment?

Comment: @TomLord - I'm not quite sure what you mean. `caller` shows only a single line: the name of the script itself. To go any further would mean displaying the stack trace of the Ruby interpreter itself, right? At any rate, my stack as displayed has one call on it.

Comment: @mwp - Yes, `$CDPATH` is set. However, I just checked and the problem persists whether or not I'm completely inside or completely outside a `$CDPATH` directory ...

Comment: Yeah, I think you need to unset CDPATH, or live with the echoing path. It's a weird rbenv thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is due to `CDPATH` being set in your environment. rbenv [`cd`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/0c7224af95aaf2df48e032dadbf3c210b6aca11a/libexec/rbenv#L43)'s while shimming Ruby and when resolving the relative path to the script file, and this causes some paths to be echoed to the terminal. In the past I've had some luck working around this issue by not exporting `CDPATH` in my `.bash_profile` (i.e. just setting it, without the `export` keyword), but it seems that this is not sufficient in all cases. In fact, in the current master branch tip of rbenv (which has not yet been released), they [`unset CDPATH`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/0c7224af95aaf2df48e032dadbf3c210b6aca11a/libexec/rbenv#L3) at the top of the file, so it seems as though they're aware of this problem and hope to address it in the next release.

If you want this fix today, instead of waiting for the next release, you can obtain it by uninstalling rbenv through Brew (`brew uninstall rbenv`), and reinstalling it through [Git](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation). You will first need to rename your current `~/.rbenv` directory (e.g. `mv ~/.rbenv ~/.rbenv.bak`), and after reinstalling rbenv, you may want to migrate your installed rubies and gems (instead of reinstalling them):

```
mkdir -p ~/.rbenv/versions
mv ~/.rbenv.bak/versions/* ~/.rbenv/versions/
```

Hope this helps!